# Excel Trend Projection

Tags: excel, vba, projection, forecasting, trend

I'm trying to find a trend projection that compares between same week of 2 consecutive years and also from previous weeks of a particular year. What is the excel formula that helps me to do this?

I need to find the projected values for week 15 all the way to week 53 for **This year**, based on

1. **The previous weeks of *This* year** (Week 1- Week 14) as well as
2. **The same week *Last* year** (Week 15)

[image: excel sheet]

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Trend function, setting Known X's to Last Year weeks 1 to 14 and Known Y's to This Year weeks 1 to 14.

Then set the New X's to the same week for last year and the function will use the Least Squares method to extrapolate for this year.

If you use absolute references (e.g. $A$1:$A$10) for the Known X's and Y's, and a relative reference for the New X's, then you can just copy/paste the formula from This Year week 15 down.

Keep in mind though that the further you get from the Known values, the less accurate the forecast becomes...

Comment: This looks good. Thanks for taking your time. Am open to other replies too.

Comment: What do I do if the values are situated across multiple worksheets? That is, one worksheet contains values for 2015 and other has values for 2016? How can I use ($A$1:$A$10) of 2015 worksheet to get the output in the 2016 worksheet?

Comment: My pleasure. It should still work regardless of where the values are stored, as long as you get the references right. You would just need to have the sheet name in front of the cells.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the add-in solver or Data Analysis?  Sometimes you have to unhide it by going to options>add-in>"Data Analysis" to use it but it does simple analyses. You will find several helpful tools for doing stats in "Data Analysis."